# What is the difference between formal group and formal group law?

Tags: elliptic-curves, formal-power-series

I heard a formal group law is a formal group with chosen coordinate.
But I cannot grasp this meaning.

My understainding; （1-dimmensional）formal group and formal group law are both element of formal power series with two variables, which satisfies some conditions（like group axiom）.
For example, $X＋Y∈K[X,Y]$ is formal additive group
law.

Could you tell me the difference between formal group and formal group law with examples?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: The two terms are often synonymous. "Formal group" is sometimes taken to be a categorification of the very concrete power series-theoretic "formal group law", as at [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/formal+group). You'll have to give your actual context to get a more helpful answer.

Comment: In 'the arithmetic of elliptic curves' written by Silverman, He denotes in Chapter 4, Formal group as pair concept like （F,f）. I don't see why such a notation is accepted. Because both F and f are element of the same formal power series, and they are completely same thing as the element of the same ring.

Comment: http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~lowdimma/BSD/Silverman-Arithmetic_of_EC.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Silverman's purposes, I think it's best if you just thought of this as a notational choice and moved on quickly to something with more content.

In any case, Silverman is clearly thinking of formal groups as objects in some category and formal group laws as a structure internal to those objects, so he uses $\mathcal{F}$ for the formal group (object in a category) and $F(x, y)$ for the formal group law (a power series). However, for his purposes in Section IV.2 there is no additional structure to $\mathcal{F}$ beyond $F(x, y)$, so you're asking why there are two symbols.

Well, you could just use $F(x, y)$, but if you did things would get awkward. For instance, a homomorphism between formal groups would then be a function $f \colon F(x, y) \to G(x, y)$ such that $G(f(x), f(y)) = f(F(x, y))$--the notation specifying the domain and codomain of $f$ is pretty misleading.

Comment: Thank you for helpful comment.I heard formal group is an group object in a category of formal scheme, and thanks to your elaborate answer, I kind of get it. If you are ok,could you tell me examples of additional structure to $\mathcal{F}$ except for $F(x, y)$?

Comment: @bellow Perhaps Section IV.3 furnishes an example of what you're after? It constructs an actual group associated to a formal group law in a certain case. Typically there's not any real additional structure beyond the power series. The group object is usually equivalently encoded in the power series.

Comment: Why the notation specifying the domain and codomain of f to be formal power series is misleading ? In what kind of sense misleading ?（I agree this is weird because domain and codomain are often sets, not element. ）

Comment: Secondly ,I wonder why formal power series is in a object of formal scheme. Objects of category of formal scheme is of course scheme, and not formal power series. What am I misunderstanding?